# JavaScriptSerializer Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

When I use the  JavaScriptSerializer in C# I'm getting a "Invalid JSON primitive" exception.  I assume the issue is with my json input string but I don't see the problem.

```
JavaScriptSerializer  new JavaScjs =riptSerializer();
js.Deserialize<Object>(json)
```

"{\"new_name\":\"Arlington\",\"new_locationid\":\"089c6c6a-f520-e111-bdd3-00505695001f\"},{\"new_name\":\"Atlanta\",\"new_locationid\":\"0a9c6c6a-f520-e111-bdd3-00505695001f\"},{\"new_name\":\"Baltimore\",\"new_locationid\":\"0c9c6c6a-f520-e111-bdd3-00505695001f\"}"

Comment: good question=>better answers

Comment: Your issue is that object doesn't have the members that are in the json if you want to convert to an object without making all the members in a costum class use the dynamic keyword: js.Deserialize<dynamic>(json)

Answer (score 3):

GoBeavs:

I validated your json here: http://jsonlint.com/

Your json text is wrong: you must enclose it with brackets ([]) when you have an array of json's. It must looks like this:

```
"[{\"new_name\":\"Arlington\",\"new_locationid\":\"089c6c6a-f520-e111-bdd3-00505695001f\"},{\"new_name\":\"Atlanta\",\"new_locationid\":\"0a9c6c6a-f520-e111-bdd3-00505695001f\"},{\"new_name\":\"Baltimore\",\"new_locationid\":\"0c9c6c6a-f520-e111-bdd3-00505695001f\"}]"
```